# Looking for a offline app to learn Spanish

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an app to learn Spanish offline.
I want to hear it while driving, so it's basically MP3 based, and not interactive.

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I am going to tag this iOS on the _guess_ you mean iOS apps - please edit the tags better edit the question to specify which computers you wish to use for this learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use the language learning apps from BYKI, both on iPhone and Mac:

http://www.byki.com/iphone/iphone.html

Servus!

Edit to add more info why I like it (as per request in comment): The iPhone version has an AUTO button on the lessons. You start the lesson when you start driving, and just let it run (with the choice in preferences to say the text in only the language to learn, or also in English). Only issue is that the version I have (Italian) sometimes stops at the end of a lesson, but not always (weird issue there). When you are not driving you can enjoy the quizzes, flip cards, etc, of course.

The Mac/Windows versions come with MP3 files that you can put onto your iPhone and play in a loop.

Comment: could you add info on why you like it, whether it works offline, etc?

Comment: Good idea! Added more info!

Answer (score 0):

A new learning platform is coming out for the iPad. If you are testing the beta version, please visit http://www.taplingua.com. It does have the off-line version but more importantly its a complete learning platform developed by a University of Chicago Ph. D

Answer (score -2):

Try this Spanish audio course http://www.spanish-bookworld.com/spanish-audio-course.html

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer.